# Runtime error in C due to algorithm checking beyond array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to make a basic sorting program that takes an integer array and sorts it in numerical order. I'm getting a runtime error when k+1 becomes greater than the array size.  I tried throwing this on the if statement: `|| (a[k + 1] != NULL)` at the end, and also `(a[k + 1] == \0)` but it doesn't compile with those.  Any tips?

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[5];

    printf("\nWill sort your numbers from lowest to highest!\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Element %i = ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    int swap;
    int i = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(a[i]); j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < j - sizeof(a[i]) - 1; k++)
        {
            if (a[k] > a[k + 1])
            {
                swap = a[k];
                a[k] = a[k + 1];
                a[k + 1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
        printf("%d\n", a[c]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int j = 0; j < sizeof(a[i]); j++)` are you sure?

Comment: `NULL` is a null *pointer*, it doesn't mean "variable (or array element) have no value". *All* array elements and variables have a value, even if it might be indeterminate if it's not initialized.

Comment: Also, and possibly more directly related to your problem, `sizeof(A[i])` will give you the size of the *element* `A[i]`, which is equal to `sizeof(int)` which is usually equal to `4`. Also, the `sizeof` operator gives you the size *in bytes*, so for your array `A` doing `sizeof(A)` will give you 20 (if `int` is four bytes). Try doing `sizeof A / sizeof A[0]` to get the number of elements of the array `A`.

Comment: `sizeof(a[i])` returns the size of the object referenced by a[i] . If it is an integer you'll probably get 4 ie 4 bytes

Comment: There's also some problems with your logic... If `j` is equal to `0`, then what is the result of `j - sizeof(a[i]) - 1` (i.e. `0 - 4 - 1`)? Your inner loop will *never* run, since its initial condition will always be false.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Due to `Usual arithmetic conversions` the inner loop will be executed many times, i.e. until the runtime error occur.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I ended up figuring it out later that day. I can't figure out how to respond with the code in a comment otherwise I would show :(

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have a mix of `signed` and `unsigned` integers here:

```
k < j - sizeof(a[i]) - 1
```

since `sizeof` is unsigned, the whole expression is evaluated as unsigned. Since `j - sizeof(a[i]) - 1` in the first loop is underflowing, you'll end up with a big number (e.g. 4294967291) so your condition is more like:

```
(unsigned)k < 4294967291
```

which leads to out of boundary accesses (and crash).

To see this, consider this code:

```
int main(void) {
    int a[5];

    for (int k = 0; k < 0 - sizeof(a[0]); k++)
    {
        printf("k=%d\n", k);
        if (k == 10) break;  // Stop after 10 prints
    }

    return 0;
}
```

At first you might expect the loop condition (i.e. `k < 0 - sizeof(a[0])`) to be false because it is like `0 < -4`. In other words - nothing should be printed!

But that is not what happens. The `-4` is taken as an unsigned value which is actually `4294967291` (after underflowing) so the loop condition is really `k < 4294967291`. In other words - you'll will print a lot.

To fix it, you can try:

```
k < j - (int)sizeof(a[i]) - 1
```

Note: This answer assumes 32 bit `int`. If `int` has a different size some of the mentioned values would be different but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I ended up figuring it out later that day. I can't figure out how to respond with the code in a comment otherwise I would show :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
sizeof(a[i])                    # size of an (one) element
```

use

```
sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])        # number of elements (as quotient)
```